# rename files with special characters in a directory

Tags: bash, file, rename

I have many photos with this template of name " 0 (0).png".
How I can rename this files with sequential numbers with Bash?
I used this:

```
for i in $(ls *.jpg); 
    do mv "$i" $(echo $a.jpg)
    let "a += 1" 
done
```

but it doesn't work.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it should work.

```
for i in *.jpg; 
do 
     let "a += 1" 
     mv "$i" "$a.jpg" 
done
```